# Avl Tree, nodes are not rotating

Tags: c++

This avl implementation should perform rotation whenever height of Node is not -1,0 or 1, I am not sure why the rotations are not working.

I also think that calcHeight func is not implemented right.is there any suggestion?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *parent, *left, *right;
    int height;
    Node(int x)
    {
        data = x; 
        left = NULL; 
        right = NULL; 
        parent = NULL; 
        height = -1;
    }
};

class AvlTree {
private:
        Node *root;
public:
       AvlTree() { root = NULL; }


        bool Find(int x) {
            return find(x, root);
        }
        bool find(int x, Node *p) {
           if (p == NULL) return false;
           if (x == p->data) return true;
           if (x < p->data) return find(x, p->left);
           find(x, p->right);
        }

        void Insert(int x) {
            root = insert(x, root);
            root = Balance(root);
         }

        //Node *AssignParent(Node *p, Node *q){
        //  if (q->left == p || q->right==p)
        //      p->parent = q;
        //      return p;
        //  return  NULL;
        //}

        Node *insert(int x, Node *p) {

            if (p == NULL)
                return new Node(x);
             if (x<p->data)

                p->left=insert(x, p->left);
             else if (x>p->data)

                p->right=insert(x, p->right);
           else
                throw "exception";
        return p;
    }

void Remove(int x) {
    root = remove(x, root);
}

Node *remove(int x, Node *p) {
    if (p == NULL)
        throw "exception";
    if (x<p->data)
        p->left = remove(x, p->left);
    else if (x>p->data)
        p->right = remove(x, p->right);
    else if (p->right == NULL)
        p = p->left;
    else if (p->left == NULL)
        p = p->right;
    else { // node p has two children
        p->data = findMin(p->right); // successor of x
        p->right = remove(p->data, p->right);
    }
    return p;
}

int findMin(Node *p) {
    if (p->left == NULL) return p->data;
    return findMin(p->left);
}

void Preorder(AvlTree b){
    preorder(b.root);
}

void preorder(Node *p){
    if (p == NULL)
        return;
    cout << p->data << endl;
    preorder(p->left);
    preorder(p->right);
}

Node *leftRotate(Node *B){
    if (B == NULL)
        throw "exception";
    Node *p = B->parent;
    Node *D = B->right;
    if (D == NULL)
        throw "exception";
    D->parent = p;
    if (p == NULL)
        root = D;
    else if (p->left == B)
        p->left = D;
    else if (p->right = B)
        p->right = D;
    B->right = D->left;
    if (B->right != NULL)
        B->right->parent = B;
    D->left = B;
    B->parent = D;
    return D;
}

Node *rightRotate(Node *D){
    if (D == NULL)
        throw "exception";
    Node *p = D->parent;
    Node *B = D->left;
    if (B == NULL)
        throw "exception";
    B->parent = p;
    if (p == NULL)
        root = B;
    else if (p->left == D)
        p->left = B;
    else if (p->right == D)
        p->right = B;
    D->left = B->right;
    if (D->left != NULL)
        D->left->parent = D;
    D->parent = B;
    B->right = D;
    return B;
}

Node *leftRightRotate(Node *D){
    Node *B = D->left;
    D->left = leftRotate(B);
    return rightRotate(D);
}

Node *rightLeftRotate(Node *B){
    Node *D = B->right;
    B->right = rightRotate(D);
    return leftRotate(B);
}

int Max(int a, int b){
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int CalcHeight(Node *p){
    if (p == NULL)
        return -1;
    int hl = CalcHeight(p->left);
    int hr = CalcHeight(p->right);
    p->height = 1 + Max(hl, hr);
    return p->height;
}

int diff(Node *p){
    return CalcHeight(p->left) - CalcHeight(p->right);
}

Node *Balance(Node *p){
    if (diff(p) > 1){
        if (diff(p->left) > 0){
            return rightRotate(p);
        }

        else
        {
            return leftRightRotate(p);
        }

    }
    else if (diff(p) < -1){
        if (diff(p->right)>0){
            return leftRotate(p);
        }

        else{
            return rightLeftRotate(p);
        }
    }
    return p;
  }
};

void main(){
    int x;
    AvlTree t;
    t.Insert(57);
    t.Insert(28);
    t.Insert(83);
    t.Insert(15);
    t.Insert(40);
    t.Insert(94);
    t.Insert(71);
    t.Insert(77);
    t.Insert(9);
    t.Insert(100);
    t.Insert(62);
    t.Insert(52);
    t.Insert(36);
    t.Insert(68);
    t.Insert(45);
    t.Preorder(t);
    cin >> x;
};
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, executing statements one at a time, which lines are causing the issue?

Comment: the program execute with no errors, however it just works as a binary search tree not an AVL tree.

Comment: Which lines are not causing the balancing?